# How do I make the 1:n relantions using SQL in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

I'm brand new to SQL and mySQL workbench. I'm trying to get the one to many relantionship from team_id to home_id and the one to many relantionship from team_name to visitor_id. I cannot get the relantionships when reverse engineering the database. How do I create these relantionships.

THis is how I created the tables. I would think the REFERENCES would created the relantionship.

```
CREATE TABLE TEAM (
    team_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    team_name VARCHAR(255),
    team_mascot VARCHAR(255)
);


CREATE TABLE GAME (
    home_id INT,
    visitor_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (home_id) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (visitor_id) REFERENCES TEAM(team_id)
);
```

Thank you for the Help

Comment: you can create the databse with the tables and run eer to get the graphs, also try every thing outyou can think of and something doesn't work ask here after extensive searching, and yes this will do what you want

Comment: Your table definitions are correct. The diagram doesn't mean that `visitor_id` is a FK to `team_name`. The FK in the diagram just references the table, not a specific column.